# iPad jQuery .Ajax is failing (when inside .NET User Control only...)

Tags: asp.net, ipad, jquery, user-controls

Our home page has an AJAX callback to fetch some simple data. On the server this call back is coded inside an ASP.NET user control.

The call back is successful when tested in IE7-9, FF3-5, Chrome, Safari5 and Opera on Windows XP, Windows 7 and Mac OS X.

The call back fails (doesn't even hit the server) when tested in Safari on iPad.

If I test the same callback from the ASPX page (rather than the user control) it works OK.

Any ideas?
Mark

Comment: iPad1 or iPad2 or both? I'm seeing some things work on iPad2 but not on iPad1.

Comment: Actually I'm testing this on iPad2. Will try and track down an iPad1 and see if there is any difference. Mark

Comment: Tested on iPad 1 and 2, same issue on both. Rgds, Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case my answer was putting `e.PreventDefault` at the start of the jQuery click event.